# Polymer Main Text is displayed on top of the drawer

Tags: html, polymer, drawer

I played around with polymer again, so I created a basic page with the help of some great tutorials on youtube but I always get this issue when opening the drawer.

[image: Image edited with Scenery (https://www.getscenery.com/)]

As you can see the menu icon and the "Polymer" title is from the bottom toolbar. Maybe somebody knows how to fix it.

Thanks :)

```
<body fullbleed layout vertical>

    <!-- Drawer -->
    <paper-drawer-panel>
        <!-- Inside the Drawer -->
        <div drawer>

            <!-- Drawer toolbar-->
            <paper-toolbar class="tall">
                <span>Menu</span>
            </paper-toolbar>



        </div>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div main class="main">

            <!-- Main toolbar -->
            <paper-toolbar>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" tabIndex="1" id="paperToggle" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                <span class="flex">Polymer</span>

                <!-- Toolbar icons -->
                <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
            </paper-toolbar>

        </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you using?

Comment: I have Polymer V1.0 and higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have slightly modified your code. Put this in your body:

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
          <paper-header-panel drawer>
            <paper-toolbar class="tall">
              <div>Menu</div>
            </paper-toolbar>

          </paper-header-panel>
          <paper-header-panel main>
            <paper-toolbar>
              <paper-icon-button icon="menu" tabIndex="1" id="paperToggle" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
              <div class="flex">Polymer</div>
              <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
              <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
            </paper-toolbar>
          </paper-header-panel>
        </paper-drawer-panel>
```

Comment: You are welcome. The paper-drawer-panel works well together with the paper-header-panel.